# Admin panel is not rendering properly

Tags: magento2, dashboard, renderer

I just made a custom module in Magento 2 and now the header and Magento admin panel is not being rendered properly.
I already upgrade the setup and clean the cache and reindex all the grid.
When I click on any module on the sidebar, it is not working. What could be the problem?

[image]

Comment: I think you have to redeploy the static content

Comment: @fmsthird do I have to do force deployment because in my case static contents are being deployed automatically.

Comment: did you try disabling your custom module to see if it works fine then?

Comment: yeah, try at least...using -f flag

Comment: @AbdulSamadAbbasi Yeah it is working fine after disabling that module but after enabling, the same issue persists.

Comment: @fmsthird did that but didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: It's hard to catch the error without looking at your code. What are you trying to do in your module for admin panel? in the meantime run this command if you haven't already `chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/static`